# Python ipywidget: Align description and boxes

Tags: python, css, ipywidgets

I want to align boxes and description in my code. Please let me know if there is a work around.

[image]
Code snippet below:

```
def helper(a,b,c):
            print (a)
TextField1= Text(value='', placeholder='Type client table name',description='Client List Name:',disabled=False)
TextField2= Text(value='', placeholder='Type flagged column name',description='Flagged column name:',disabled=False)
TextField3= Text(value='', placeholder='Type columns name',description='Columns name:',disabled=False)
x=interactive(helper,a=TextField1,b=TextField2,c=TextField3)
display(x)
```

I tried to reference another stack page and tried a code that worked for one of the users which was as below

[image]

But it did not seem to be working for me.

[image]

code snippet below:

```
from ipywidgets import widgets
from IPython.display import Javascript, display

align_kw = dict(
    _css = (('.widget-label', 'min-width', '20ex'),),
    margin = '0px 0px 5px 12px'
)
platform_ui = widgets.Dropdown(description = 'platform',options=['iPhone','iPad','Android'], **align_kw)
event_type_ui = widgets.Text(value='open', description='Test Event', **align_kw)
os_version_ui = widgets.Text(value='iOS9', description='Operating System', **align_kw)
refresh_ui = widgets.Checkbox(description='Force Refresh', **align_kw)

display(platform_ui,event_type_ui,os_version_ui,refresh_ui)
```

Comment: Please add your code as code to the article, not as images. You can do so by putting 4 spaces before the code.

Comment: Sure! Adding the same! Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

I raised the issue on their git page as well. Please refer to https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/1849 for solution